# How to generate Java classes from .XSD using xjc?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb

I have a large .xsd file and I want to generate Java classes from there. I can't access xjs because it's not in my JDK as I'm using the latest Java SDK. I'm finding an easy and quick way to install it and use it locally.

Currently, I'm getting an error message:

Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/xjc" (-1)

Comment: Download it from https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/

Comment: I did, I see bin folder insde jaxb-ri and xjc.bat and xjc.sh, what are the next steps?

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch04.html#tools-xjc

Comment: Didn't manage to export/make xjc globally accessible.