# getting the value of an XML subnode using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to map this XML file using JAXB and get the value of the `CODE` element. Ultimately, the full XML file will inlude many charge code blocks and I'll need to extract all the values of the different tags, but right now all I want is to manage to get one value.

The XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tpDoc>
  <tpCTRL>
      <DocID>CHARGE CODES</DocID>
      <SenderID>IES</SenderID>
  </tpCTRL>
  <PAYLOAD>
   <CHARGE_CODE>
    <CODE>TEST</CODE>
    <DESCRIPTION>M Test</DESCRIPTION>
    <SALES_ACCOUNT>34535</SALES_ACCOUNT>
    <COSTS_ACCOUNT>500056756745</COSTS_ACCOUNT>
   </CHARGE_CODE>
  </PAYLOAD>
</tpDoc>
```

This is the umarshalling code:

```java
public class XMLtoJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Inbar\\OneDrive\\OneDrive - alfacloud.co.il\\MSF\\Developments\\OrdertoCashThirdPartyProcess(B2B)\\MSF XMLFiles\\ChargeCodesSmall.XML");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CC.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        CC chargeCode =  (CC) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputFile);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(chargeCode.getCode());
    }
}
```

The class:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="tpDoc")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CC {

    @XmlElement(name="CODE")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @XmlElement(name="SALES_ACCOUNT")
    private String salesAccount;
    @XmlElement(name="COSTS_ACCOUNT")
    private String costsAccount;


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

However, all I get is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tpDoc` doesn't have the fields you specify in `CC`. It has a `PAYLOAD` which contains a `CODE` and the other elements. In other words, your definition in `CC` does not match the XML structure.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So am I suppose to somehow create another class called payload or can I somehow tell this tpdoc class the proper subchild structure? In other words what do i do to fix this while creating as few classes as possible.

Comment: You can use an online tool such as [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) to convert a sample XML file into an XSD. And then you can use the `xjc` tool (bundled with Java 8 or also available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839364/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-xsd-using-xjc)) to use that XSD to generate the Java class/classes needed to represent the XML structure.

Comment: Suggestion: When generating your Java classes, make sure your sample XML includes multiple `<CHARGE_CODE>` sections, since that is ultimately what you need, and that will change the structure of the Java, compared to an XML sample which only has a single `<CHARGE_CODE>` entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you and you should be able to get any values. I have used `Project Lombok` for `Getter and Setter methods`. Also, skipped the POJO for `tpCTRL` you need to add them

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tpDoc>
    <tpCTRL>
        <DocID>CHARGE CODES</DocID>
        <SenderID>IES</SenderID>
    </tpCTRL>
    <PAYLOAD>
        <CHARGE_CODE>
            <CODE>TEST</CODE>
            <DESCRIPTION>M Test</DESCRIPTION>
            <SALES_ACCOUNT>34535</SALES_ACCOUNT>
            <COSTS_ACCOUNT>500056756745</COSTS_ACCOUNT>
        </CHARGE_CODE>
    </PAYLOAD>
</tpDoc>
```

tpDoc:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "tpDoc")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class tpDoc {
    @XmlElement(name="PAYLOAD")
    private Payload payload;
}
```

Payload;

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Payload {
    @XmlElement(name="CHARGE_CODE")
    private ChargeCode chargeCode;
}
```

ChargeCode;

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChargeCode {
    private String CODE;
    private String DESCRIPTION;
    private String SALES_ACCOUNT;
    private String COSTS_ACCOUNT;
}
```

main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(tpDoc.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final tpDoc tpDoc = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, tpDoc.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(tpDoc.toString());
        System.out.println(tpDoc.getPayload().getChargeCode().getCODE());
        System.out.println(tpDoc.getPayload().getChargeCode().getCOSTS_ACCOUNT());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(tpDoc.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(tpDoc, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is the output;

```
tpDoc(payload=Payload(chargeCode=ChargeCode(CODE=TEST, DESCRIPTION=M Test, SALES_ACCOUNT=34535, COSTS_ACCOUNT=500056756745)))
TEST
500056756745
<tpDoc>
   <PAYLOAD>
      <CHARGE_CODE>
         <CODE>TEST</CODE>
         <DESCRIPTION>M Test</DESCRIPTION>
         <SALES_ACCOUNT>34535</SALES_ACCOUNT>
         <COSTS_ACCOUNT>500056756745</COSTS_ACCOUNT>
      </CHARGE_CODE>
   </PAYLOAD>
</tpDoc>
```

Comment: Great sutff, thanks.
I was wondering.
If i need to then use the values I extract for other things like validation versus a database and so on...
Do i write getters for this data in the unmarshalling Class to be used in other packages?

Comment: `@Data` annotation on each class is coming from `Project Lombok` which has the `Getter` and `Setter` so you not need to write any additional `Getter` if you are using the `Poject Lombok` with `@Data` on the respective `POJO Classes`. Glad to help. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: To accept the answer as well? All you need to do is click on the `CHECK` button next to my answer and click on the `^` symbol next to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers